# How to redirect from http://localhost/goog to www.google.com for users

Tags: node.js

I am unable to understand how to redirect a user from localhost to https://www.google.com. Methods to achieve the same are expected as suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you want to redirect to `Google` when user visits `http://localhost/goog` (and assuming your using `Express`) you can try :

```
app.get("/goog", (req, res) => {
    res.status(301).redirect("https://www.google.com");
});
```